# What are the differences between CAST and CONVERT mysql functions?

Tags: mysql

What are the differences between CAST and CONVERT mysql functions?

Only that the function СONVERT is not a standard DB ?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the syntax that's slightly different, from a functionality point of view, they seem to be identical.

Regarding standards, to quote from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html):

> CONVERT(... USING ...) is implemented according to the standard SQL specification.